# Offline Mapbox Confusion

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I need help in the "Offline Maps" section, I have been trying to implement this function for a while and I have something done but it doesn't work, I know that Mapbox has its own plugin but I can not implement it in my application. This is my code from develop branch.

I post my code issue on GitHub, in case someone can see carefully what I have done and maybe I can give a solution. Currently it seems that it will download the map but it stays in an infinite loop and does not download. It may be easier to use the Offline Mapbox Plugin but I do not know how to configure it.

https://github.com/Jeluchu/mapboxU/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for Mapbox.*

It looks like you didn't create an instance of the OfflineManager before trying to download. You should have a line something like this:

`val offlineManager = OfflineManager.getInstance(this@MainActivity)`

For setting up the Android plugin, the instructions are available here: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/offline/

That should walk you through installation, dependencies, etc.